# Масштабируемость текста в виджетах при изменении размера формы Qt Designer

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, qlayout, resizeevent

Для компоновки элементов я использую `layouts`. Это хорошо работает, когда есть текстовые поля, таблицы и т.д. Но на некоторых вкладках моего приложения нет таких элементов, а есть только `buttons` и `labels`.

При использовании на таких вкладках `layouts` кнопки растягиваются (но выглядит это не очень), `labels` тоже растягиваются, но текст в них остаётся неизменным.

Я подумала, что на таких вкладках будет логично увеличить масштаб всех элементов, а не растягивать их, как в [**приложении с примерами PyQt5**](https://github.com/pyqt/examples):

**Стандартный размер:**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**При изменении размера на максимальный:**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Как мне сделать что-то подобное и возможно ли такое сделать через *Qt Designer* или только в коде на *Python* (при загрузке файла **.ui**, без конвертации в **.py**)?

**Update:**

Вот пример, с файлом **.ui**: на форме **`три`** элемента `label`, `textedit` и `button`, они помещены в вертикальный менеджер компоновки. 
При изменении размера формы кнопка и таксовое поле растягиваются, `label` остаётся неизменным.

Как сделать, чтобы текст и в `label`, и в  `textedit` увеличивался?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Файл .ui на меге](https://mega.dp.ua/ru/vs9MSRyG)

**Python код:**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi('test.ui', self)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**test.ui:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>399</width>
    <height>413</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
    <item>
     <widget class="QLabel" name="label_2">
      <property name="styleSheet">
       <string notr="true">font-size: 24px;</string>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>Задача организации</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item>
     <widget class="QTextEdit" name="textEdit">
      <property name="styleSheet">
       <string notr="true"/>
      </property>
      <property name="html">
       <string>&lt;!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC &quot;-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN&quot; &quot;http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd&quot;&gt;
&lt;html&gt;&lt;head&gt;&lt;meta name=&quot;qrichtext&quot; content=&quot;1&quot; /&gt;&lt;style type=&quot;text/css&quot;&gt;
p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }
&lt;/style&gt;&lt;/head&gt;&lt;body style=&quot; font-family:'MS Shell Dlg 2'; font-size:8.25pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;&quot;&gt;
&lt;p style=&quot; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:10px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; background-color:#ffffff;&quot;&gt;&lt;span style=&quot; font-family:'Source Sans Pro'; font-size:8pt; color:#333333; background-color:#ffffff;&quot;&gt;Таким образом новая модель организационной деятельности представляет собой интересный эксперимент проверки направлений прогрессивного развития. Значимость этих проблем настолько очевидна, что постоянный количественный рост и сфера нашей активности обеспечивает широкому кругу (специалистов) участие в формировании существенных финансовых и административных условий.&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p style=&quot; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:10px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; background-color:#ffffff;&quot;&gt;&lt;span style=&quot; font-family:'Source Sans Pro'; font-size:8pt; color:#333333; background-color:#ffffff;&quot;&gt;Не следует, однако забывать, что постоянное информационно-пропагандистское обеспечение нашей деятельности способствует подготовки и реализации новых предложений. Идейные соображения высшего порядка, а также начало повседневной работы по формированию позиции влечет за собой процесс внедрения и модернизации новых предложений.&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/body&gt;&lt;/html&gt;</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item>
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
      <property name="text">
       <string>PushButton</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>399</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

**test.py:**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(399, 413)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("font-size: 24px;")
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label_2)
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit.setStyleSheet("")
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.textEdit)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 399, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Задача организации"))
        self.textEdit.setHtml(_translate("MainWindow", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:8.25pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:10px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; background-color:#ffffff;\"><span style=\" font-family:\'Source Sans Pro\'; font-size:8pt; color:#333333; background-color:#ffffff;\">Таким образом новая модель организационной деятельности представляет собой интересный эксперимент проверки направлений прогрессивного развития. Значимость этих проблем настолько очевидна, что постоянный количественный рост и сфера нашей активности обеспечивает широкому кругу (специалистов) участие в формировании существенных финансовых и административных условий.</span></p>\n"
"<p style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:10px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; background-color:#ffffff;\"><span style=\" font-family:\'Source Sans Pro\'; font-size:8pt; color:#333333; background-color:#ffffff;\">Не следует, однако забывать, что постоянное информационно-пропагандистское обеспечение нашей деятельности способствует подготовки и реализации новых предложений. Идейные соображения высшего порядка, а также начало повседневной работы по формированию позиции влечет за собой процесс внедрения и модернизации новых предложений.</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
```

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте ваш [mcve] , который демонстрирует проблему.

Comment: @S.Nick добавила

Comment: не надо никаких ссылок, опубликуйте `test.ui` также как и код

Comment: @S.Nick добавила, но а если мне нужно работать с файлом **.ui**, не конвертируя его в **.py**?

Comment: так а зачем вы опубликовали  `.py`, а не `test.ui` ?

Comment: Скорее всего средствами Qt Designer такое сделать нельзя. Если нужно по своему масштабировать элементы, то скорее всего придется переопределять `resizeEvent` для `QLabel` и `QTextEdit` в классах-наследниках.

Comment: @S.Nick добавила `test.ui`, просто когда я ранее так делала, мне сказали, что он битый и что правильно конвертировать его в `.py`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В *Qt Designer* такое сделать нельзя.

Вам надо будет переопределять `paintEvent` соотверствующих классов:

```
class Label(QLabel):
    ...
        def paintEvent(self, event):
            ...
```

или как посоветовал  @Bogdan переопределять `resizeEvent`, примерно так:

Обратите внимание, что я переписал вводимый текст в **`формате html`** как **`простой текст`**.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, uic
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(399, 413)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
#@        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("font-size: 24px;")                  # ---
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label_2)
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit.setStyleSheet("")
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.textEdit)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 399, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
#        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
#        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
#        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Задача организации"))
        
        self.textEdit.setHtml(_translate("MainWindow", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:8.25pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:10px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; background-color:#ffffff;\"><span style=\" font-family:\'Source Sans Pro\'; \
font-size:8pt; color:#333333; background-color:#ffffff;\">Таким образом новая модель организационной деятельности представляет собой интересный эксперимент проверки направлений прогрессивного развития. \
Значимость этих проблем настолько очевидна, что постоянный количественный рост и сфера нашей активности обеспечивает широкому кругу (специалистов) участие в формировании существенных финансовых и административных условий.</span></p>\n"
"<p style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:10px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; background-color:#ffffff;\"><span style=\" font-family:\'Source Sans Pro\'; \
font-size:8pt; color:#333333; background-color:#ffffff;\">Не следует, однако забывать, что постоянное информационно-пропагандистское обеспечение нашей деятельности способствует подготовки и реализации новых предложений. Идейные соображения высшего порядка, а также начало повседневной работы по формированию позиции влечет за собой процесс внедрения и модернизации новых предложений.</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        

class Window(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.font = QtGui.QFont()
        self.font.setFamily("Arial")
        self.font.setPointSize(14)        
        self.setFont(self.font)

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        w = self.size().width()
        if  w < 150:
            self.font.setPointSize(8)        
            self.setFont(self.font)
            self.textEdit.setFontPointSize(8)
        elif 150 <= w < 300:
            self.font.setPointSize(10)        
            self.setFont(self.font)
            self.textEdit.setFontPointSize(9)
        elif 300 <= w < 600:
            self.font.setPointSize(14)        
            self.setFont(self.font)
            self.textEdit.setFontPointSize(12)
        elif 600 <= w < 800:
            self.font.setPointSize(24)        
            self.setFont(self.font) 
            self.textEdit.setFontPointSize(15)
        elif 800 <= w < 1000:
            self.font.setPointSize(34)        
            self.setFont(self.font) 
            self.textEdit.setFontPointSize(20)
        elif 1000 <= w < 1200:
            self.font.setPointSize(44)        
            self.setFont(self.font) 
            self.textEdit.setFontPointSize(25)
        elif w >= 1200:
            self.font.setPointSize(54)        
            self.setFont(self.font) 

        self.textEdit.setPlainText(self.textEdit.toPlainText())      # +++ setPlainText


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: спасибо за помощь!

Comment: @Афродита пожалуйста

Comment: а данный метод  не работает, если задан `styleSheet`? Даже если я добавляю пустые стили, например `QPlainTextEdit { }`, шрифт уже не меняется.

Comment: @Афродита если у вас возникают другие проблемы - задайте новый вопрос, приведите свой пример и расскажите что вы хотите сделать и что у вас не получается.